# Menu com class ativa em php?

Tags: php, menu, url-amigável

Tenho um menu em html :

```
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="ativa">Página Inicial</a></li>
            <li><a href="servicos">Serviços</a></li>                  
            <li><a href="entretenimento">Entretenimento</a></li>
            <li><a href="festas-e-decoracoes">Festas e Decorações</a></li>
            <li><a href="bares-e-restaurantes">Bares e Restaurantes</a></li>    
            <li><a href="beleza-e-estetica">Beleza e Estética</a></li>
            <li><a href="hoteis-e-pousadas">Hotéis e Pousadas</a></li>
            <li><a href="esportes-e-suplementos">Esportes e Suplementos</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Porém quero que ele seja em php devido ao banco de dados que criei para url amigável, por exemplo: /categorias/servicos

Como faço para o meu menu continuar com class ativa, mas sendo feita em php?

O código é para um getMenu mas não sei se está correto.

```
public function getMenu(){
        $pegar_categorias = "SELECT * FROM 'categorias' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $executar = self::conn()->prepare($pegar_categorias);
        $executar->execute();
        if($executar->rowCount()==0){}else{
            while($categoria = $executar->fetchObject()){
                echo '<li><a href="'.Path.'/categoria/'.$categoria->slug.'">'.$categoria->titulo.'';
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }

    }
```

Obrigada!

Comment: Onde está o código php ? Ao menos o php deveria ter informação sobre qual página é a corrente e essa informação deve estar relacionada ao menu.

Comment: Editei e adicionei o código php!

Comment: Faz um `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; exit;` bem no topo da página e poderá ter uma noção de onde começar.

Comment: Seguindo o que o @DanielOmine falou, compara a `$categoria->slug` com a `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` pra colocar um class "ativa" na li que for relacionada com a pagina que esta aberta